# SOQL Sorting Question

Tags: apex, soql

I have an opportunity with related products:

[image]

I use the following SOQL query to get a list of Opportunity Products

```
Opportunity opp = [SELECT Id, (SELECT Product2.Name FROM OpportunityLineItems 
    ORDER BY Product2.Name ASC)FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :oppId LIMIT 1];
```

I expect the same sorting order returned by the query. Apparently it's not:

[image]

Seems that "Digit Zero" comes after "Latin Capital Letter B" [link](https://unicode-table.com/en/)

Does anybody know why it is so?

Comment: Thats quite possible, 'did you try sorting by `Product2Id` instead to see the result?

Comment: @EduardY I think the ASCII value of `0-9` is between 31-40 (don't know exact range) and Alphabets start from 65. That is why you got that output.

Comment: @RahulSharma I don't need to sort by Product2Id, but by Name. I am not sure that sorting by Product2Id will result in the correct alphabetical order.

Comment: @RohitMourya exactly ASCII value of 0-9 is between 31-40, and logically they should go before Alpha since "Digit Zero" (30) < "Latin Capital Letter B" (42). But the output is "Latin Capital Letter B" first and "Digit Zero" next, which is not the expected outcome.

Comment: @EduardY. Oh.. my bad. I misread your expected and actual output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I do know is that the result of a SOQL query using a ORDER BY statement is influenced by the current user's locale. The [**documentation**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_orderby.htm) states this:

> Sort order is determined by current user locale. For English locales, Salesforce uses a sorting mechanism based on the UTF-8 values of the character data. For Asian locales, Salesforce uses a linguistic sorting mechanism based on the ISO 14651 and Unicode 3.2 standards.

This might be related to your issue, and you might want to try changing the locale to see if there is a difference.

Now speaking about the sorting itself: if I create a list of strings with your product's names the system seems to order them correctly using the `sort` method.

```
List<String> names = new List<String>{
        'OPC01010001',
        'OPC01030000',
        'OPC07070001',
        'OPC12120001',
        'OPC14160001',
        'SPCB1401',
        'SPCB1403',
        'SPCB1404',
        'SPC0105CH',
        'SPC1016BK',
        'SPC1016RS'
};
names.sort();
for (String n : names) {
    System.debug(n);
}
```

This code gives me the following result:

[image: result]

If you can't solve the issue by changing the locale, you might want to take a look at ordering the records using this method, or even implementing the [**Comparable interface**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_comparable.htm) in your query result.

Comment: indeed you are right about user's locale. I checked my user's locale and it appeared to be "Spanish (Spain)". I initially looked at the documentation, but this saying "For Asian locales,..." just assured me that different sorting mechanism is used FOR ASIAN locales only. It comes out to be not. They should write "For Non-English or other locales..." Anyway that you very much for your answer.